# How to answer to xp_cmdshell?

Tags: ssms, xp-cmdshell

I am using SSM and I want to export data with xp_cmdshell. It looks like this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select id, data from tabla" queryout C:\temp\data.dat -S 10.11.11.111 -U XXX -P XXX '

PRINT @sql

EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

It gives me the result:

```
Enter the file storage type of field id [int]:
```

So now I have to set datatype for the column id. My problem is I cannot 'answer' to xp_cmdshell. I can't use cmd, becuse I am reaching the SQL server via VPN and it is not seeing my bcp.exe.

How do I give answer in SSMS xp_cmdshell?

Comment: You might be better off asking this question on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I suspect you have an X/Y problem, and there's an easier way to do a bulk export without invoking bcp via xp_cmdshell.

Comment: And what would that be?

Comment: I don't know, which is why I'm suggesting you ask on the site dedicated to DB questions.

Comment: Oh, sorry, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the `-c` (lowercase c) parameter, which indicates to use the character data type for the storage type.  The following statement will export the results of your query.

```
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select id, data from tabla" queryout C:\temp\data.dat -c -S 10.11.11.111 -U XXX -P XXX '
```